# Searching for finding SE site Or others Website alternatives to ask about Chemotherapy side effects edema

Tags: support

I have a question about my Medical Sciences Stack Exchange post: [Edema after injecting Docetaxel chemotherapy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/edema-after-injecting-docetaxel-chemotherapy)

This question recognized as off-topic question, so i like to know Which SE Site or similar SE site i can ask this type question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal medical advice are on-topic on https://www.reddit.com/r/AskDocs/, so you can ask your question there.

Answer (score 2):

If you look up [docetaxel](https://www.drugs.com/sfx/docetaxel-side-effects.html) on a reputable drug info site, you'll see that blistering, peeling and loosening of the skin are common side effects of the drug (it's the third side effect listed). So there's really no need to ask here. It's already known to be a common side effect, and the answer you would get would likely be the same link I just gave you.

I don't think there is an SE site where the question would be welcome. You could always ask on Quora or Reddit, but again, I think you'll just get linked to the site I gave you or another one like it.

I closed your question because it appeared you were asking about someone you know who's experiencing this, and that makes it a request for personal medical advice. If I misunderstood and your question is actually "What is the pathopharmacological cause of the blistering?" then that's a very different question and would be allowed. If so, you can edit your question to clarify and it may be reopened, but my guess would be it's not fully understood so you won't get a good answer, and if it is understood the answer is going to be complex and not readily understood by someone without advanced training in pharmacology and medicine.

Oh, and welcome to the site and thank you for reading enough to figure out this is the correct place to ask about your question, and for doing so in a polite, mature fashion.